# List: display one item at time

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf

I would like to have a loop which would go through each element of the list once. 
If the button is clicked, then the message box displays only first element of the list. If is clicked second time, it shows next element, and so on...

I created in the User class private void with this code:

```
    public void ClickNext()
    {
        List<int> test = new List<int>();
        test.Add(0);
        test.Add(1);
        test.Add(2);
        int next = test[index + 1];
        MessageBox.Show(next.ToString());
     }
```

int index is initialised outside void.

In the window the code presents itself like this:

```
     private void buttonRight_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       u1.ClickNext();
    }
```

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: How are you manipulating `index` ?

Comment: looks like you making a counter?

Comment: Not very clear what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize counter as field

```
private int counter = 0;
```

And click btn

```
 public void ClickNext()
{
   List<int> test = new List<int>();
        test.Add(0);
        test.Add(1);
        test.Add(2);

        int msg = test[counter%list.Count];
        MessageBox.Show(msg.ToString());
        counter++;
 }
```

When it comes to last element it will go back to beginning (first element).

Answer (score 1):

Obviously a lot more will need to go into it to work with whatever you're doing. But the core concept is just to declare your Index and add 1 to it after each click. You'll need to add in some error handling in case your index is larger than the list length.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var test = new Clicker();
            test.ClickNext();
            test.ClickNext();
        }
    }

    class Clicker
    {
        public int Index { get; set; }

        public void ClickNext()
        {
            var listStr = new List<string>
            {
                "item 1",
                "item 2",
                "item 3"
            };
            var next = listStr[Index];
            Index++;
            MessageBox.Show(next);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this hope its helps

```
var Index=0; 
    public void ClickNext()
     {
            List<int> test = new List<int>();
           for(int i=0;i<=2;i++)
           {
            test.Add(i);
        //test.Add(0);
       // test.Add(1);
       // test.Add(2);

           }      
          if(Index<=test.Last())
             {
               MessageBox.Show(test[Index].ToString());
             }
          else{
              MessageBox.Show("End");
             //reset Index
             Index=0; 
             }
    }

     private void buttonRight_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

           u1.ClickNext();
          Index++;
        }
```

Comment: can someone explain for down vote? because I really want to know what I did wrong and improve on this.Thanks